# android classcastexception at android.app.Application

Tags: android, classcastexception

i have the following exception when i running the following application

Activity:

```
package com.google.android.SmartStudentmCompanion;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends  Activity{
    public static String ip_address="192.168.1.101";

    EditText username; 
    EditText password;
    Button login;
    Button exit;
    Toast toast;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);
        System.out.println("onCreate()...");
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        this.login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        this.login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String usrnm;
            String pwd;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                usrnm = username.getText().toString();
                pwd = password.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("onClick()...");
                int length = 0;
                try {
                    System.out.println("hello");
                    String page = executeHttpPost(usrnm,pwd);
                    System.out.println(page);
                    length = page.length();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (length == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Invalid username and/or password", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Valid username and password", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), VideoViewer.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

            }
        });

        this.exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exitButton);
        this.exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }


    public String executeHttpPost(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {

            ApplicationEx app = (ApplicationEx)this.getApplication();

            HttpClient client = app.getHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://"+ip_address+"/smartstudentmcompanion/check.php");
            List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("un", username));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", password));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(formEntity);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            /*in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();*/
            String page = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            System.out.println("page: " + page);
            return page;
            } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Application:

```
package com.google.android.SmartStudentmCompanion;

import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

public class ApplicationEx extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = "ApplicationEx";
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        httpClient = createHttpClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        shutdownHttpClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        shutdownHttpClient();
    }
    private HttpClient createHttpClient(){
        Log.d(TAG,"createHttpClient()...");
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);
        SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
        schReg.register(new Scheme("http",
                PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        schReg.register(new Scheme("https",
                SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
        ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,schReg);
        return new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);
    }

    public HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        return httpClient;
    }

    private void shutdownHttpClient() {
        if(httpClient!=null && httpClient.getConnectionManager()!=null) {
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.google.android.SmartStudentmCompanion"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">



    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Login"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".VideoViewer"></activity>


    </application>

     <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: 1.  Formatting.  2. Where's the exception?

Comment: Please post the entire exception stack trace, and point out which line of code it is referring to.

Comment: The only casts I see in your code are associated with the findViewById calls in the Activity. Check your layout(s) and verify that Views created there match the ones expected by the code (Buttons and EditTexts.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your manifest change

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

to

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".ApplicationEx">
```

Since you have not stated the `android:name` for the `<applicaton>` the OS looks for the default `Application` class. In order to point it to your `Application` subclass you should use `android:name` attribute.