# How do I get rid of this Class Cast Exception error in my code?

Tags: java, android, class, global-variables, classcastexception

I created a GlobalVariables class to share variables across multiple classes. But Im now having problem with classcastexception. I have been reading about this exception and I know that I cant cast an instance of main class to the sub class. Still not sure how to change it in my code to get rid of it. Please take a quick look at my `TextPlay class` where

```
        GlobalVariables gs = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
        gs.setTestMe(getUserId);
        tvUserId.setText("Copied");
```

is. Thanks a lot!

**Globalvariables class**

```
public class GlobalVariables extends Application {

private String testMe;

public String getTestMe() {
    return testMe;
}

public void setTestMe(String testMe) {
    this.testMe = testMe;
}

}
```

**TextPlay Class**

```
public class TextPlay extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button chkCmd;
ToggleButton passTog;
EditText input;
TextView display;
EditText etUserId;
Button btnUserId;
String getUserId;
TextView tvUserId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);

    baconAndEggs();
    passTog.setOnClickListener(this);
    chkCmd.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Share variables between classes controls
    etUserId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserId);
    btnUserId = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUserId);
    tvUserId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUserId);


    btnUserId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getUserId = etUserId.getText().toString();
            // Store Global Variables in GlobalVariables class
            GlobalVariables gs = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
            gs.setTestMe(getUserId);
            tvUserId.setText("Copied");
        }
    });
}

private void baconAndEggs() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
}

public void onClick(View v) {


    }
}
}
```

**error log**

```
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.armstrong.y.android.app.GlobalVariables
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at com.armstrong.y.android.app.TextPlay$1.onClick(TextPlay.java:48)
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   01-22 06:12:23.898: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Manifest**

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.armstrong.y.android.app"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >

      <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

      <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.armstrong.y.android.app.NumCounter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.armstrong.y.android.app.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.armstrong.y.android.app.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TextPlay"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Email"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DailyDataEntry"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WeeklyDataEntry"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Camera"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".InitialDataEntry"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FinalDataEntry"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Rankings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Data"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OpenedClass"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GlobalVariables"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
      </application>

  </manifest>
```

Comment: Make your `GlobalVariables` class `Serializeable` and use it any where you want in your project

Comment: The general answer is "cast what is castable". In this particular case it is too little information given.

Comment: Just making the class serializable won't solve the class cast exception.

Comment: Rather than this, store them in a shared preference so that it can be accessed the same way as a global variable as well as you can check the values too

Comment: @Praveen I just added some part of the error log

Comment: @MoJo do you have a good example of using shared preference? Thanks

Comment: Have you declare your `GlobalVariables` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: @Praveen yes I have.    <activity
            android:name=".GlobalVariables"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14452814/940096)

Comment: @EthanXu: I've suggested it for a semilar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226761/using-data-fetched-in-one-activity-in-another-activity/12226967#12226967

Comment: @Praveen tried and no luck. getting the same casting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code to initialize your class object that extends `Application`

```
 GlobalVariables gs = (GlobalVariables) ActivityName.this.getApplicationContext();
```

UPDATED ANSWER:
In manifest.xml,

in `application`tag, use `android:name= "<your_package_name>.GlobalVariables"`
donot declare it as an `Activity`.

Comment: it still crashes and threw classcastexception error

Comment: good call. I changed that and still have the same fatal error ClassCastException which causing it to crash. I think the application code has to be modified somehow.

Comment: I think I got it. I had to change the application name to  my application class. In my case, GlobalVariables. Thanks a lot! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317676/android-classcastexception-at-android-app-application

Comment: @EthanXu: i have explained the same

Comment: Yup, I think you nailed it on the head. I just didnt get it right away. New to android

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Application` object is not `GlobalVariables`. I expect that you are not declaring `GlobalVariables` to be your application object in the manifest. You will need to do that for the class cast exception to go away. (Add something like `android:name=".GlobalVariables"` as an attribute to the `<application>` tag.)

**However!** Don't implement global variables by extending `Application`. It's not necessary; just create either a singleton class or a class with static data. If necessary, maintain an "initialized" flag that can be checked and used to perform initialization when needed.

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html):

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton.

Comment: I added GlobalVariables to the manifest but still having that problem. I will take a look at singleton class and class with static data. Thanks

Comment: @EthanXu - If `GlobalVariables` is in a different package than your application package, you will need to use the fully qualified name in the manifest. It might be useful to post your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Just posted the manifest. thanks

Comment: @EthanXu - I see that you accepted PattabiRaman's answer, which is essentially (after his update) the same as the first part of my answer. Glad that it worked for you.

Comment: Oh yea, I just noticed it too. Sorry. I didnt realize you meant the Application tag in the manifest. That was spot on!