# class cast exception in one project not in other

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, classcastexception

I was following [GCM Tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139) and I took utmost care in making no mistake and implementing same code in my project. But when I run the project I am getting `ClassCast` exception. I thought I would have missed something so I downloaded the source from that post and copied each and every line carefully in my project but still I am getting same exception. Please help solve the error.

```
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exaple.oldgcm/com.exaple.oldgcm.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.exaple.oldgcm.Controller
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.exaple.oldgcm.Controller
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at com.exaple.oldgcm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
12-10 23:41:25.812: E/AndroidRuntime(9549):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you haven't set an Application name in your manifest.

Refer to this solution:

[android classcastexception at android.app.Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317676/android-classcastexception-at-android-app-application)